# n largest files in a directory

Tags: python

This is a script I wrote to find the *n* biggest files in a given directory (recursively):

```
import heapq
import os, os.path
import sys
import operator

def file_sizes(directory):
    for path, _, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for name in filenames:
            full_path = os.path.join(path, name)
            yield full_path, os.path.getsize(full_path)

num_files, directory = sys.argv[1:]
num_files = int(num_files)

big_files = heapq.nlargest(
        num_files, file_sizes(directory), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print(*("{}\t{:>}".format(*b) for b in big_files))
```

It can be run as, eg: `bigfiles.py 5 ~`.

Ignoring the complete lack of error handling, is there any obvious way to make this clearer, or at least more succinct? I am thinking about, eg, using `namedtuple`s in `file_sizes`, but is there also any way to implement `file_sizes` in terms of a generator expression? (I'm thinking probably not without having two calls to `os.path`, but I'd love to be proven wrong :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace your function with:

```
file_names = (os.path.join(path, name) for path, _, filenames in os.walk(directory)
        for name in filenames)

file_sizes = ((name, os.path.getsize(name)) for name in file_names)
```

However, I'm not sure that really helps the clarity.

I found doing this:

```
big_files = heapq.nlargest(
        num_files, file_names, key=os.path.getsize)
print(*("{}\t{:>}".format(b, os.path.getsize(b)) for b in big_files))
```

Actually runs slightly quicker then your version.

Comment: That's an interesting result. How did you time it? You wouldn't think that twice as many syscalls would speed it up!

Comment: @lvc, I used `time python script.py`. Its not making twice as many sys calls because I'm only making the second call for the top 5 or so files.

Comment: Ah, indeed, it will only be `num_files` extra syscalls. Presumably, what's happening is that constructing multiple tuples is more expensive - if that's the case, we could expect the difference to shrink and eventually go away as `num_files` approaches the number of files searched. But, when I look at it, I think I do prefer `key=os.path.getsize` over my many tuples for clarity, anyway.